# Problemas no makefile ao trocar de debian para freebsd (ifeq e endif)

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang

Estou usando netbeans para compilar alguns programas em C/C++ ele compila remotamente os códigos em uma maquina debian (GNU), tudo funciona sem problemas problemas, porém tentei compilar o mesmo projeto em um freebsd que usa CLANG, eu estou tendo erro:

```
make: "contrib/contrib/Makefile-Jenkins.mk" line 2: Missing dependency operator
make: "contrib/contrib/Makefile-Jenkins.mk" line 4: Need an operator
```

Na linha 2 eu tenho o comando ifeq e na linha 4 endif em todos os locais que uso 
ifeq  e endif estou tendo esses erros.

Esse Makefile foi eu quem fiz e variável UID_DIR_LIB normalmente não é sequer passada a não ser quando eu compilo o projeto pelo jenkins.

```
ifeq ($(UID_DIR_LIB),)
    UID_DIR_LIB := .
endif
```

Alguém sabe como corrigir para funcionar em ambas as plataformas?

Comment: `ifeq` não é POSIX, é uma GNU-extensão. Você pode instalar `bmake` para verificar o seu makefile. Aqui é [um bom link](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/08/20/).